# General rule/s for finding out whether an object is accusative or dative

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative, rules

I wanted to know whether there are some general rules or hunches in the German mind that hints at whether an object has accusative or dative case.

For example there are some rules to determine the gender of a word, such as if it ends with `-ung`, it is feminine. With this rule and others, it is possible to guess the gender of a random word with a high degree of success.

I know that the case has to do with the transitivity of the verb and the objects' being direct (Akk.) or indirect (Dat.). But sometimes what feels like a direct object is used with accusative, e.g. `gratulieren`. Because in English you *congratulate someone*, not *congratulate to someone*.

Another is `fragen` (Akk.) which can was previously explained [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40839/why-does-fragen-take-two-accusatives).

These are exceptions and have to be dealt with individually. My question is: are there any rules that can help determine the case? For example allow us to reconstruct [this list](https://www.pons.de/daten/pdf/Praxis-Grammatik/04_Verben_mit_Dativ-_und_Akkusativobjekt.pdf) with %80 accuracy without prior knowledge?

Comment: There actually is only one, but very simple rule: Look in the dictionary to find out. And, BTW, the list you're linking to is *verbs and prepositions* - That's a different story, here, in most cases, the preposition drives the case, not the verb any more..

Comment: Sorry, I changed the list to the correct one.

Comment: When discussing German, thinking in direct/indirect object categories will only confuse, never help you. Forget about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your goal is 80% accuracy in knowing the cases a verb takes, here's the trick:

- Learn the verbs which go with the nominative case:

> sein, werden, bleiben, heißen

- Learn the verbs which go with double accusative:

> abfragen, abhören, angehen, fragen, lehren, kosten, nennen, rufen, schelten, schimpfen, taufen, unterrichten

- Learn the common verbs which go with genitive:

> anklagen (Akk+Gen), sich annehmen, bedürfen, sich bedienen, sich bemächtigen, beschuldigen (Akk+Gen), sich erinnern, sich erfreuen, harren, gedenken, sich schämen, spotten, sich vergewissern

Now, you have learned three short lists. There are no more lists to learn. Only two simple rules:

- Check if the verb has the accusative object *built-in* and may be described as an action of **giving**. Those verbs often take a dative object, which is the **receiver** of that built-in accusative object.

> (ihm) antworten – (ihm) eine Antwort **geben**
>
> (ihm) helfen – (ihm) Hilfe **zukommen lassen**
>
> (ihm) glauben – (ihm) Glauben **schenken**

- Check if the verb action means providing a service. Those verbs often take a dative object, which is the **receiver** of that service. You may see this as a special case of the above rule.

> (ihm) zuhören – (ihm) Gehör **schenken**
>
> (ihm) gefallen – (ihm) Gefallen **schenken**
>
> (ihm) gehorchen – (ihm) Gehorsam **zukommen lassen**

Almost all other verbs either take no object, a lone accusative object, or first an accusative object, then a dative object, which is also some kind of **receiver**.

This gives you more than 80% accuracy already. If you wanted to reach almost 100%, you had to learn the common exceptions from the two rules above, which are not too numerous.

Comment: +1 I like your rule, I have used it myself before. I want to add to learn the true reflexive verbs that take a reflexive pronoun in dative (short list). From *Hammar's* a good rule is:  Verbs with certain prefixes usually take a dative: *bei-, ent-, entgegen-, nach-, wider-, zu-*. Examples: beistehen, beiwohnen, entsagen, entstammen, entgegengehen, nachlaufen, nachstellen, widerstehen, zulaufen, zustimmen,,,etc.

Comment: @User what do you mean by Hammar's?

Comment: @osolmaz This is my shortcut to the most famous German grammar book in English IMHO :) *Hammer's German grammar and usage*

Comment: @User: these *bei-*, *ent-*, *nach*, and *zu-* prefix rules are full of exceptions. *beigeben, beilegen, beifügen, beibehalten, beibringen …*, *entasten, entleeren, entladen, entstellen,…*, *nachahmen*, *nachbearbeiten, nachbehandeln, nachkochen, …*, *zubauen, zubereiten, zustellen, zustecken …* For *entgegen-*, *wider-* you are right, though there are some exceptions, too: *Entgegenbringen, widerlegen …*.

Comment: @Janka I like to think of adverbs of frequency in terms of percentages: always= 100%, frequently= 90%, usually 60%- 80%, often= 70%, sometimes= 50%, occasionally= 40%, seldom= rarely= 20%, never= 0%. Hammer's used *usually*; So, of course it's full of exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try a somewhat different approach.

> **Statement 1: Most German verbs take the accusative case.**

a) **Echte transitive Verben**

Rule: When transforming the active sentence to a passive one, the *Akkusativobjekt* becomes the *Subjekt* of the passive sentence. **Aus Akkusativ wird Nominativ.**

> Er isst **den** Apfel. -> **Der** Apfel wird von ihm gegessen.
>
> Er trinkt **einen** Grog. -> **Der** Grog wird von ihm getrunken.
>
> Er hat **einen** Tisch gekauft -> **Der** Tisch ist von ihm gekauft
>   worden.
>
> Das Regime hat **den** Film verboten. -> **Der** Film wurde vom Regime
>   verboten.

CONCLUSION? When the pattern described above works, you can be 100% sure that your *Akkusativ* is correct.

b) **Pseudotransitive Verben**

They do take the accusative case, too, but the active sentence cannot be transformed to a passive one.

> Wir **behalten** deinen Schlüssel (Akk.).  IMPOSSIBLE: * Dein
>   Schlüssel wird von uns behalten.
>
> Der Autor hat einen Preis (Akk.) **bekommen**.   IMPOSSIBLE: * Der
>   Preis wurde vom Autor bekommen.
>
> Der Koffer **enthält** zehn Hemden (Akk.).  IMPOSSIBLE: * Zehn Hemden
>   werden vom Koffer enthalten.
>
> Wir haben Ihren Brief  (Akk.) **erhalten**.   IMPOSSIBLE: * Ihr Brief
>   wurde von uns erhalten.
>
> **Es gibt** wundervolle Menschen (Akk.) auf dieser Welt.  IMPOSSIBLE: * Wundervolle Menschen werden auf dieser Welt gegeben.
>
> Die Lampe **kostet** 40 Euro (Akk.).  IMPOSSIBLE: * 40 Euro werden von
>   der Lampe gekostet.
>
> Das Gelände **umfasst** (= hat; misst) 200 Hektar (Akk.).  IMPOSSIBLE: *
>   200 Hektar werden von dem Gelände umfasst.
>
> Dein Verhalten **wundert** mich (Akk.) sehr.  IMPOSSIBLE: * Ich werde von deinem Verhalten gewundert.

CONCLUSION? *behalten, bekommen, enthalten, erhalten, es gibt, kosten, umfassen & wundern* are the most frequent pseudo-transitive verbs. Adding an accusative object means 100% correctness.

> **Statement 2: The number of verbs that take the dative case is rather small.**

Rule: When transforming the active sentence to a passive one, the *Dativobjekt* does NOT become the *Subjekt* of the passive sentence. **Dativ bleibt Dativ.**

> Sie droht **ihm** mit einer Anzeige. -> **Ihm** wird [von ihr] mit
>   einer Anzeige gedroht. NOT: * Er wird gedroht.
>
> Ich glaube **dir** nicht. -> **Dir** wird [von mir] nicht geglaubt.
>   NOT: * Du wirst nicht geglaubt.
>
> Er hilft **seinem Bruder** -> **Seinem** Bruder wird [von ihm]
>   geholfen. NOT: * Sein Bruder wird geholfen.
>
> Er verzeiht **seinem** Vater. -> **Seinem** Vater wird [von ihm]
>   verziehen. NOT. * Sein Vater wird verziehen.

ATTENTION! Some *Dativ-Verben* cannot undergo a passive transformation whatsoever.

> Du fehlst **mir**. IMPOSSIBLE: * Ich werde von dir gefehlt. or: * Mir
>   wird von dir gefehlt.
>
> Dieses Bild gefällt **ihr**. IMPOSSIBLE: * Sie wird von diesem Bild
>   gefallen. or: * Ihr wird von diesem Bild gefallen.
>
> Das nützt **ihm** nichts. IMPOSSIBLE: * Er wird nichts genützt. or: *
>   Ihm wird nichts genützt.
>
> Der Pullover steht **dir** gut. IMPOSSIBLE: * Du wirst von dem
>   Pullover gut gestanden. or: * Dir wird von dem Pullover gut gestanden.
>
> Die Hose passt **mir** nicht. IMPOSSIBLE: * Ich werde von der Hose
>   nicht gepasst. or: * Mir wird von der Hose nicht gepasst.

CONCLUSION?  When you can remember the verbs in the *Liste der wichtigsten Verben mit Dativ-Ergänzung*, you can be 100% sure that your *Dativ* is correct. The list is here: https://mein-deutschbuch.de/dativ-ergaenzung.html

So what do you say? 100% instead of 80% only, that's quite something, isn't it? Or maybe I should say 97%, in order to keep out of harm's way.

A final hint. Never, never ever learn isolated verbs. Learn them with their structure(s). Thus: jd**m**. etw. (A.) geben; etw. (A.) bei jd**m**. hinterlegen; jd**n**. von etw. (D.) überzeugen, jd**n**. vor etw. (D.) warnen *et cetera*

Comment: This is (though it is a good answer) just a complicated way of saying "if in doubt, look it up" ;)

Comment: This **approach totally depends on the native speaker instinct.** The passive constructions depend on the active ones.  I can make a *similar* approach with a 100% accuracy to know the gender of a noun. Suppose you don't know the gender of the word *Schule* and thus you don't know which definite article to use in nominative *der, die, or das*. You can try to put the demonstratives in the nominative case before the noun: if *dieser* works, *Schule* is masculine; if *diese* works, *Schule* is feminine; and if *dieses* works, *Schule* is neuter. I don't think this would work for non-natives.